# How to apply Motion Blur to objects in Cycles?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, objects, compositing-nodes, motion-blur

I am wanting to apply Motion Blur but seems like I can get the blur only on the car. I am wanting to apply motion blur on the rendered background with no blur to the car except the wheels (to show the speed of the car). I don't have a background and there all objects in the scene. I am using Cycles. Is there a way to apply it just on the rendered background?

[image]

Comment: You might be able to achieve this by isolating the object with the cryptomatte pass.

Comment: How could I do that?

Comment: but you know that motion blur only "works" if the object moves right? so if you background doesn't move...you won't see motion blur...

Comment: Judging by this image I can tell that the car is the only moving object in your scene hence the result. If you want the background blured, try to move your camera along with the car or use the compositor.